# Pass std::string to WriteConsole API

Tags: c++, winapi

When I compile and link the following program, it doesn't show me any issue.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char* argv)
{
    std::string cMessage = "Native Windows Development.\n";
    WriteConsole(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), cMessage.c_str(), cMessage.size(), NULL, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

But when I execute the program, it shows me just a bunch of ????? sign in the console. what is the problem with the code? Why I can't use std::string rather const char* ?

Comment: Try changing the function name to `WriteConsoleA`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the character set is Unicode so WriteConsole expects a wchar string.  You have two choices.

1) Do everything in unicode

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv)
{
    std::wstring cMessage = L"Native Windows Development.\n";
    WriteConsole(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), cMessage.c_str(), cMessage.size(), NULL, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

2) Set the default character set to mbcs

Comment: There is a third choice, as I mentioned above.

Comment: That is what changing the character set to mbcs will do

Comment: Your first choice is wrong. If you want to *"do everything in Unicode"*, the signature of the entry point is `wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])`.

Answer (score 2):

The `?` output indicates that you are compiling for Unicode, where `WriteConsole()` maps to `WriteConsoleW()`.  Since you are wanting to write `char` data, use `WriteConsoleA()` instead:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char* argv)
{
    std::string cMessage = "Native Windows Development.\n";
    WriteConsoleA(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), cMessage.c_str(), cMessage.size(), NULL, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```